# Populate bootstrap modal with content just when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with lists like this, which is been populated from a php loop

```
| **name**   | **age**  | **course** | **action**      |

| wilson     | 56       | Web pro    | edit  delete    |
```

the edit button looks like

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/edit/{$row['id']}" data-href="#myModal">Edit</a>
```

I have a modal already which shows up when the edit is being clicked but I want a situation where when I click the edit button the url `localhost/admin/edit/3` where 3 is an id is run and a database query getting details of the user with id = 3 and is returned to the view which will now be populated into the modal.

I know this will probably be an ajax thing but I really don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Remote content is explained in the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am using codeigniter so it was hard implementing the suggestions, i later got it to work by doing this:

on the button that triggers the modal i hyave:

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/profile/edit/<?php echo   $row['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" >Edit</a>
```

then below my code i have:

```
<?php if(@$show_edit_modal): ?>
<script>$("#edit_modal").modal('show'); </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

on the admin/profile/edit:

i had

```
public function profile($arg1="", $arg2=""){

if($arg1=='edit' && !(empty($arg2)){
$data['profile'] = my qyuery to get the row where id=$arg2;
$data['show_edit_modal']=true; //this set to true so when the page loads modal will pop up
$this->load->view('mypage'); //page loads and modal pops up then on modal i can access my data from database
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send an ajax request with parameters as id,then fetch the required data from Database.Return the json encoded data.Then using javascript decode the data and then populate it as required in your modal pop up.